# How to add title (tooltip) on selectpicker disabled option?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a *selectpicker* with many languages i.e. `<li>` tags under `<ul>` tag as below given image.

[image: Drop Down List (selectpicker)]

It can be seen that the **+ Add Language** `li` of *selectpicker* is disabled. It is happening because in actual html's `<select>`'s `option` is disabled as following image

[image: HTML view]

Now the concern is:
selectpicker picks the select option and apply all the properties but did not carry the title (it can bee seen on `<select>`'s `<option>` value; `title="My Title"`) while hover over the disabled `<li>` tag. In my opinion it is happening because disabled class on this `<li>` tag is overriding the title behavior by adding that ***ban*** icon.

Please let me know how can I enable this behavior while using select picker. I want title to be displayed while hovering over the disabled option.

**Edit:**
Kindly refer to the code snippet for better understanding.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
Language:
<select class="selectpicker">  
    <option>English</option>
    <option disabled title="My Title">+ Add Language</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: I can't understand what is the expected result? How to `title` should looks like without the `disabled` attribute. Can you create a **working** [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for this?

Comment: Expected behavior is when I hover over the + Add Language it should show me the tool tip My Title along with the ban red icon...

Comment: Are you using a library for the tooltip or do you mean the native browser tooltip?

Comment: Native Browser tooltip. Actually, the disabled property is overriding this feature by displaying the ban red icon.

Comment: I don't see the `title` attribute on the `li` or the `a`. Is there a `title` attribute in a not disabled `li`?

Comment: Yeah exactly. That's because when selectpicker was generating ul li from select it did not copy the tittle attribute.. That's my main question. It is not copying the behavior when I do this $("#languageid").selectpicker('refresh');. I'm sorry I'm not quite good at putting the question... But I hope you understood it now. If still not let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118402/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-mukesh-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute [`data-content`](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#custom-content)

From the docs:

```html
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option data-content="<span class='label label-success'>Relish</span>">Relish</option>
</select>
```

With this attribute you can pass the output "template" there you can set a `title` attribute.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Language:
<select class="selectpicker">  
    <option data-content="<span title='English'>English</span>">English</option>
    <option disabled title="My Title" data-content="<span title='+ Add Language'>+ Add Language</span>">+ Add Language</option>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to top, here is my code:

```
<select class="selectpicker"> 
    <option value="add" data-content='<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="My Tooltip Title">+ Add Language</span>'>+ Add Language</option>
</select>
```